# android animation - make a view appear from center to the width of screen

Tags: android, xml, animation

I'm trying to make an animation to display a progressbar. the way I want it is to display the view in the center then continuously grow to both way until it hit the width of the screen. so the progressbar will go like this

```
       -               1% long
      ---              10% long 
     -----             20% long
    -------            30% long
   ---------           50% long
```

In this case, X will remain the same all the time while Y will start from 0 until 100 (but start from the center). 
Can someone please help? or is there a good tutorial on android animation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved! just for future reference. this is what I got

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale android:fromXScale="0.1" android:toXScale="1.0"
      android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
      android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="100%"
      android:duration="2000" />
</set>
```